# State Vuex don't work correctly with Nuxt.js Problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

**I'm trying to set state vuex on my Nuxt.js App, but it don't work correctly.** 
So here i'm set my state with fetch method:

```
fetch({app, store, route}) {
    app.$axios.$get(`apps/${route.params.id}`)
      .then(res => {
        store.dispatch('setApp', {
          ...res,
          id: route.params.id
        })
        console.log(app.store.state.app);
      })
  }
```

Here everything works correcty when i'm logging app.store, data is there,
but when i'm trying to log it in:

```
  created() {
    console.log(this.$store);
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store);
  }
```

Here's my store code:

```
const store = () => new Vuex.Store({

  state: {
    app: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    'SET_APP' (state, payload) {
      state.app = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setApp (ctx, payload) {
      ctx.commit('SET_APP', payload)
    }
  },
  getters: {

  }
})
```

**i't don't work my state is empty so data is not render on my template (
I hope that somebody gotta help me !**

***P.S: Also when it's logging on client-side everything works fine, but in SSR not (***

Comment: Could you please add the `setApp` action to your question ? And also, I don't think that you are logging in the right place, since the `created` and `mounted` lifecycle hooks will be executed before your `fetch` will be done.

Comment: @ThomasFerro yes sure, now you can watch on it )

Comment: @ThomasFerro i don't know but data is not rendering on my template ( it's empty it works only if it on client-side

Comment: Thanks, can you try to log your $store in a computed based on the `app` state ?

Comment: @ThomasFerro on the app state, you mean on the fetch method or the index file on store folder ?

Comment: On the same component as your `created` and `mounted` lifecycle hooks.

Comment: @ThomasFerro yes it's, empty too, it works only on fetch method

Comment: @ThomasFerro only on fetch method it's not empty. But when it updated on client-side it works correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated from the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/)

> To make the fetch method asynchronous, return a Promise, Nuxt.js will wait for the promise to be resolved before rendering the component.

In code example above, axios request is made inside `fetch` hook, but Nuxt will not wait for it to resolve, as no promise is returned, so it keeps rendering the component, thus running `created` and `mounted` hooks, which by the time of invocation do not have filled `$store`.

In order to make it work, you should return a promise from `fetch` method.

If no additional code is present in your app, simply adding `return` statement will solve the issue:

```
fetch({app, store, route}) {
  return app.$axios.$get(`apps/${route.params.id}`)
    .then(res => {
      store.dispatch('setApp', {
      ...res,
      id: route.params.id
    })
    console.log(app.store.state.app);
  })
}
```